# How to display all data from a column

Tags: python, sqlite

There is a database in it there are columns with names: bellang, bellit ... How can I display all the numbers from the bellang column

[image: db]

Need to output 9 5 7

I tried cursor.fetchall()[] but the output is [(9,),(5,),(7,)]

Comment: Doesn't this "display all the numbers from the bellang column"? This is a list of tuples, you can iterate over it and display values as you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using cursor, you need to do this way

```
rec = []
records = cursor.fetchall()
for row in records:
    rec.append(row[0])
    cursor.close()
```

Or alternatively, using list comprehension

```
_cursor = cursor.fetchall()
rec = [row[0] for row in _cursor]
cursor.close()
```